# Foundation: confusion over $medium-screen variable and _grid-5.scss

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation Sass version 4.3, and have just started using the framework a couple of days ago, so apologies for my ignorance.

Currently I rely on the `$small` and `$large` media query variables, as well as the `small-` and `large-` class names for changing the layout of my site at different dimensions.

My current understanding:

- "small" means anything below the value of `$small-screen` (eg, `@media only screen`)
- "large" means anything above the value of `$small-screen` (eg, `@media #{$small}`)

Now I would think, when using the `_grid-5.scss` component file to give me `medium-` classnames, that it would be using the value of `$medium` (eg, `@media #{$media}`) and change the meanings of "large"

I would expect it to change to:

- "small" means anything below the value of `$small-screen` (eg, `@media only screen`)
- "medium" means anything above the value of `$small-screen` (eg, `@media #{$small}`)
- "large" means anything above the value of `$medium-screen` (eg, `@media #{$medium}`)

But there is no relationship between the `$medium` variable and the `medium-` classnames! In-fact, the media query dimensions are hard-coded into `_grid-5.scss`.

I'm really confused here.

If anyone is able to answer the following questions it would be most helpful:

- Why is there no relationship between the `$medium-screen` variable and the `medium-` grid classes?
- Should I be importing both `_grid.scss` and `_grid-5.scss` components?
- Is there better documentation out there that describes the correct use of the `_grid-5.scss` file and how to use the `$small`, `$medium` and `$large` variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to DNFS over on the  Foundation Framework mailing list/google group, I now have clarification on this matter.

To answer my own questions:

```
Why is there no relationship between the $medium-screen variable and the medium- grid classes?
```

This was a bug, and has been recently fixed: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/ae4fa9027acfee0970683236fe3765580444a3ff

```
Should I be importing both _grid.scss and _grid-5.scss components?
```

_grid-5.scss is a complete replacement for _grid.scss (the -5 suffix means it's going to be part of foundation 5 and is currently a pre-release preview of the new grid system)

Google groups discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foundation-framework-/8kFzJtVUV7k